# Как избавиться от вложенного цикла в Си

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Имеется следующая задача:Получить упорядоченный по возрастанию массив С, содержащий все элементы массива А, которых нет в В. Значения в массивах А и В упорядочены по возрастанию.
Так же имеются ограничения, одно из которых это запрет на использование вложенного цикла. Есть функция которая выполняет эту задачу, но она с вложенным циклом. Как можно избавиться от вложенного цикла в этой функции?

```
    int all_element_mass_A(int *mass_C, int *mass_A, int *mass_B, int size){
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size-6;i++){ //size - 6 это кол-во элементов в массиве
    bool flag = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < size-6;j++){
        if(mass_A[i] == mass_B[j]){
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag){
        if(mass_C[count] != mass_A[i]){
            mass_C[count] = mass_A[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подозреваю что вы пропустили в условии факт отсортированности исходных массивов

Comment: Отдельно вызывает недоумение size-6

Comment: size-6 можно заменить на 4 (кол-во элементов в массиве)

Comment: **Если** массивы как-нибудь упорядочены, то это будет всего один цикл с двумя индексами. Исправьте вопрос про входящие данные, это важно.

Comment: Нужно именно отсутствие вложенных циклов или просто решение с линейной асимптотикой?

Comment: Сказано, что нельзя использовать вложенные циклы, а также цикл, моделирующий вложенный цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/tsTl8P

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *filter(int *a, int *aend, int *b, int *bend, int *c)
{
  while (a < aend)
    if (b == bend || *a < *b)
      *c++ = *a++;
    else if (*a == *b)
      ++a;
    else
      ++b;
      
  return c;
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[] = {2, 5, 6, 11};
  int b[] = {2, 4, 6, 9};
  int c[64];

  int *cend = filter(a, a+4, b, b+4, c);
  
  for (int *p=c; p<cend; ++p)
    printf("%d ", *p);

  return 0;
}
```

```
5 11
```