# Сравнение множеств С++

Tags: c++

```
void compareset(set<string> A, set<string> B) {
    vector <string> H;
    set<string> ::iterator it1; // объявляем итератор
    set<string> ::iterator it2;
    
    for (it1 = A.begin(),it2 = B.begin(); it1 != A.end() && it2 != B.end(); ++it1, ++it2) // пока итератор не достигнет последнего элемента
    {
        if (*it1==*it2) H.push_back(*it1);// и переходим к следующему элементу
        ;
    }
    for (string i : H) {
        cout << i;
    }
    
}
```

Мне нужно сделать функцию,которая сравнивает два множества(set) и в вектор записывает общие элементы.Желательно не использовать методы по типу intersection,find,count и тд.Мне нужно вручную с помощью итераторов это сделать.У меня не особо получается...

Comment: [set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) смотрим раздел possible implementation. Впитываем алгоритм.

Comment: Сделайте вложенный цикл, который будет управлять итератором второго множества. А из внешнего цикла его уберите. Тогда будет работать. А сейчас вы сравниваете первый элемент с первым, второй со вторым, третий с третьим и т.д.

Comment: Вот, я недавно [такое писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1381353/178988) - у тебя почти так же.

Comment: @maestro, тогда, скорее всего, будет квадратичная асимптотика. Хотя можно и с линейной написать при вложенном цикле.

Comment: Стоп, а почему бы просто наличие не проверять?

Answer (score 0):

По идее, должно работать вот так:

```
for (auto &x : A)
  if (B.count(x))
    H.push_back(x);
```

Comment: Это так выглядит линейная асимптотика? "Желательно не использовать методы по типу intersection,find,count и тд."

Comment: спасибо,работает.потом попробую еще через итераторы сделать.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, блин, это ж плюсы. Нет, это n*lb(m). В случае с hash set была бы линейной.

Comment: @MaximLeo, кажется, я немного накосячил. Но вариант с итераторами я ссылку в комментарии давал - тебе там только условие поменять.

Comment: Во,через итераторы заработало.Теперь все работает как надо.